# Regex matching *,à and?

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching, expression

Regex the most difficult one for me.I need the regex for below in Java

`1) 17-08-15 11.04A &AD4 USFR EN 00*`

```
My TRY:\d[1-9]+\-\d[1-9]+\-\d[1-9]+\s+\d[1-9]\.\d[1-9]+\w+\s+&+\w+\d\s+\w+\s+\w+\s+\d+
```

& and *>>Is the first problem and if there is any better regex for the above one please suggest.

`2)17-08-15  11.04A &AD4 USER 0002******** j? j? à?&AD4N`

**PROBLEM**>> ******* and ?,&,` how to include these in regex.

I have googled a lot but only simple regex's are available.And the tools are generating all constant type regex taking the strings as it is in reg ex like

```
16\-09\-14\s+11\.04A\s+&AD4\s+USER\s+EN\s+00
```

It contains everything as it is so this kind of regex are not useful to me.

Thanks

Comment: You are giving 2 examples. Fine. But could you tell what the rule is ? If not the trivial regex `.*` matches !

Comment: There are no rules just need to validate it against a regular expresion,that regex i am trying to build.

Comment: downvoter care to comment? if you know the answer if you dont find complete info?

Comment: I think this is a good one...why are the downvotes coming without any solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To search for some special characters (like & and *) you need to escape them by putting `\` in front: `\*`, `\&`.

1) Your regex is wrong. As far as I understood first group represents the date, so your regex will work even for such date: `32-99-15`. The same applies for time. You can check it here: https://regex101.com/r/tX1iD9/2

Here is the regex for the date and time part until ampersand `17-08-15 11.04A`:

```
(0[1-9]|[12]\d|30)-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-[0-9]{2}\s(0\d|1[1-2])\.([0-5]\d){1,2}(A|P)\s\&
```

It supports 12-hour time with `A` or `P` at the end and proper date, you can test it here: https://regex101.com/r/mF9dQ9/3

And for the whole string you can find regex here: https://regex101.com/r/mF9dQ9/4

2) Regex for the second:

```
(0[1-9]|[12]\d|30)-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-[0-9]{2}\s+(0\d|1[1-2])\.([0-5]\d){1,2}(A|P)\s\&[A-Z]{2}\d\s+[A-Z]{4}\s+(\d|\*){12}\s\w\?\s\w\?\s\à\?\&\w{2}\d\w
```

https://regex101.com/r/eT8eY6/1

Comment: take it as a pattern of string which should be similar to what you can see above.

Comment: how come your regex is better? two regex for two strings

Comment: Nice try with so little initial info ! But I think you could have left `\s+` instead of a simple `\s` as the `+` was in initial OP's try. @user3560140 : if you do not say what the following string is we won't be able to give the regex.

Comment: @SergeBallesta:What would you need as info? take them as normal string and help with regex.I find the above expression no different from the one i provided.What would be really helpful how to include &,?,******** AND if you can compare my regex with streetturtle

Comment: What I need, if what can be after what streetturle have guessed of the begin of your strings. Is it really anything ? is it exactly `&AD4 US` followed by anything ? or is it exactly one of both strings ? or ...

Comment: Thanks turtle for updating.Let me test it now :) The first string might look like a date :P but i did not put a condition in my regex to get it checked against a valid date.Actually this string came to me from unknown source and they don't know what it represents :P Else it would have been easy to tackle this.But the only point i was struck was those special charactes * à .